# Xcode: memcpy EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode, memcpy

I get the following crash when I build and run:

[image]

[image]

Here's the message I see in my debugger (NOTE: I do have Guard Malloc & Log Malloc Stack enabled).

```
GuardMalloc[MyApp-63254]: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.
GuardMalloc[MyApp-63254]:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.
GuardMalloc[MyApp-63254]:  - Applications using vector instructions (e.g., SSE) should work.
GuardMalloc[MyApp-63254]: version 107
MyApp(63254,0x1062a3300) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.63254.10e133000.MyApp.kmVU0O.index
MyApp(63254,0x1062a3300) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks to disk using standard recorder
MyApp(63254,0x1062a3300) malloc: process 63063 no longer exists, stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.63063.113aba000.MyApp.WTSUw0.index
```

Here's my entire method:

```
- (MatrixObject *)matrixByRemovingColumnAtIndex:(int)index {

    // In this example this should be 2
    NSLog(@"int debug: %d", index);

    //Store new column size
    int newColumnCount = (columnCount - 1);

    //Make sure our index is not out of bounds
    if (index > newColumnCount) {

        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Index Out Of Bounds Exception"
                                       reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Oops! %@'s index input is out of bounds. Maximum bounds allowed is: %d.", [self class], columnCount - 1]
                                     userInfo:nil];
    }

    //Create new double array
    double *newMatrix = malloc(rowCount * newColumnCount * sizeof(double));

    /*
     We need to copy in 3 steps.
     Step 1: Copy first row elements before our column at index.
     Step 2: Copy every row in every column except for our column at index rows
     Step 3: Copy last row elements after our column at index.
     */

    // Do Step 1
    memcpy(newMatrix, self->matrix, index * sizeof(double));

    //Total number of elements
    int allElements = (rowCount * columnCount);

    //Simplify our index
    int i = (index + 1);

    //Do Step 2 while looping through all our rows in our columns
    do {

        //Copy every element
        memcpy(newMatrix + index, self->matrix + i, newColumnCount * sizeof(double));

        //Increment our index by our newColumnCount
        index += newColumnCount;

        //Increment our i by columnCount
        i += columnCount;
    }

    //Loop through all our rows in our columns until we reach the end
    while ((i < allElements) && ((i + columnCount) < allElements));


    // Do Step 3 (Don't forget our rows after our column at index bc we want those)
    if (i < allElements) {

        //Copy our last elements (THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS)
        memcpy(newMatrix + index, self->matrix + i, (allElements - i) * sizeof(double));
    }

    return [[self class] matrixFromDoubleArray:newMatrix withRows:rowCount andColumns:newColumnCount];
}
```

Has anyone experience this type of crash with memcpy. NOTE: This method is called from a `MatrixObject` subclass, but I doubt that affects this.

Comment: Objective C is not C++ nor C...

Comment: True, but memcpy and malloc are, and that's the root of the problem.

Comment: your `memcpy(double_ptr + int` looks fishy. Could be fine but looks fishy :)

Comment: You are experiencing a segmentation fault, you should run your program through a debugger (like lldb) and ensure that all counter and index have a correct value. EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are writing or reading area of the memory that have not been allocated

Comment: @JonathanPotter Objective-C *is* C, it is a strict superset. All C code is also valid Objective-C. All C constructs are valid Objective-C. Objective-C is a thin layer added to C.